# Make input table with initial entries and save changes with tikinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am trying to make an input table in Python using tkinter. The input table has initial values that can be changed. When alle the inputs have been edited, I want to save the changes. I use TinyDB as database to store the input values.

Can someone show an easy example on how to do that?

Comment: This site isn't a free coding service. We expect you to do the initial work. Please do some research, perhaps work through a tutorial, and then ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out and posted my example below. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I concur with Bryan on this one, a quick example of storing multiple inputs with `tkinter` can be found below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = []

def command(entry):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(entry)):
        output.append(entry[i].get())
    print(output)

for i in range(10):
    entry.append(Entry(root))
    entry[i].pack()

Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:command(entry)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This creates 10 `entry` elements and uses a command triggered by a `button` to store all of them in a `list`.

Comment: Thank you. I have written some code lines below that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I see I got a lot of critical responses for not showing my initial code. I think I found the solution when typing this simple example, it seems to work OK. Have to make it Object oriented, though.

```
from tkinter import *
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

# Name on database with stored parameter values (confined and free parameters)

param_db_name = 'db5.json'  
db2 = TinyDB(param_db_name)  

# Get field name and values for free parameters in Model1:

model_name = 'Model1'  
felt = Query()  
fields = (db2.search(felt.Model_name == model_name)[0]['free_par']).keys()  
fields_val = (db2.search(felt.Model_name == model_name)[0]['free_par']).values()  
#print('Fields_val: ',fields_val)  

def save_params(entries, fields):  
   res_dict = {}
   for field in fields:
      res_dict[field] = float(entries[field].get())
   print('Res dict:', res_dict)
   felt = Query()
   db2.update({'free_par': res_dict}, felt.Model_name == model_name)

 def makeform(root, fields,ff):
   entries = {}
   i = 0
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=32, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      ent.insert(0, [ff[i]])
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries[field] = ent
      i=i+1
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.wm_title("Model parameters")
   ents = makeform(root, fields, list(fields_val))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Lagre',command=lambda: save_params(ents,fields))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Avslutt', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

## The db2 database consists of two entries:

```
[{'Model_name': 'Model1','con_par': {'CPar1': 1, 'CPar2': 2, 'CPar3': 3.0},'free_par': {'FPar1': 0.589, 'FPar2': 1.44, 'FPar3': 3.0, 'FPar4': 2.427}},
 {'Model_name': 'Model2','con_par': {'CPar1': 11, 'CPar2': 12, 'CPar3': 13.0},'free_par': {'FPar1': 10.589,'FPar2': 11.44,'FPar3': 13.0,'FPar4': 12.427}}]
```